# Replace USB3-A jack with USB-C

Tags: usb, schematics, usb-c

I am new to PCB design and I want to use a USB-C port instead of a USB3-A port, but in the documantation I have only found how to use a USB3-A port.

I have come up with a sulution, but I am not sure if my solution will work.

(I don't know if it works so please don't use it if you also don't know if it works)

[image: My Solution for the problem (I have no glue if it works so don't use it if you don't have one either)]

Answer (score 0):

First, this arrangement won't work without 56k pull-up on CC pin (or 22k, or 10k, depending).

Second, even with CC pull-up, this arrangement will violate USB Type-C specifications, since VBUS should not be asserted until proper CC-connection is detected by port's electronics.